# Cache tiles for offline use of Google/Bing aerial maps

Tags: google-maps, tiles, tilecache, bing-maps

I am currently working on a project where QGIS is used for creating and editing vector data and requires a Google or Bing aerial photo layer as a basemap.  I can add Google satellite/Bing aerial photos as a base map layer using the OpenLayers plugin but I am looking for any solution that I can use to do this offline using local cached tiles.

Comment: This is a duplicate of another SO question (not on the GIS site):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109369/how-to-cache-google-map-tiles-for-offline-usage

And also, this very question goes against Google's Terms.  Unless you are a Premier member, you're not allowed to cache tiles.

Comment: It's worth noting that caching Google tiles is not against the T&C. What is against the rules is pre-fetching (what the OP is actually asking). (See [10.1.3 Restrictions against Copying or Data Export](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms).)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tilestache-seed.py script of the really good and light [TileStache](http://tilestache.org/) library. You could use [TileCache](http://tilecache.org/) also.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a local apache server, and change the target URLs in the openlayers plugin to  `http://localhost/path/to/your/tiles...`

Answer (score 2):

Caching Bing Maps tiles for offline use is against the terms of use of Bing Maps.

Answer (score 1):

I found an explanatory doc and c# code here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx

written by Bing's software architect, Joe Schwartz.

I see (in 2017) browser requests like
   https://t1.ssl.ak.dynamic.tiles.virtualearth.net/comp/ch/03131020103313233?mkt=en-GB&it=A,G,RL&shading=hill&n=z&og=146&c4w=1

where '03131020103313233' is a quadtree-key ('quadkey'),
deciphered as per the above link like this (c) microsoft 2017

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts a QuadKey into tile XY coordinates.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="quadKey">QuadKey of the tile.</param>
/// <param name="tileX">Output parameter receiving the tile X coordinate.</param>
/// <param name="tileY">Output parameter receiving the tile Y coordinate.</param>
/// <param name="levelOfDetail">Output parameter receiving the level of detail.</param>
public static void QuadKeyToTileXY(string quadKey, out int tileX, out int tileY, out int levelOfDetail)
{
    tileX = tileY = 0;
    levelOfDetail = quadKey.Length;
    for (int i = levelOfDetail; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int mask = 1 << (i - 1);
        switch (quadKey[levelOfDetail - i])
        {
            case '0':
                break;
            case '1':
                tileX |= mask;
                break;
            case '2':
                tileY |= mask;
                break;
            case '3':
                tileX |= mask;
                tileY |= mask;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid QuadKey digit sequence.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can downlaod Google maps for offline use with GoogleMapsRipper from http://www.blueblackworks.com

There is Batch downlaod mode - to do massive download, if needed.
Not sure how legal is all this, but is doable.