# Google maps, download entire province/region from google maps

Tags: google-maps, maps

Is there a way to download a region from Google maps to a PDF or JPEG file? I would like to download as many zoom levels as possible so I can zoom in and out without being online. I need this for practical reasons when I will be traveling to remote China and I need detailed maps of certain provinces/counties.I will be browsing these maps on an iPod touch.

I only need the street information, so only the "map" part of gmaps.

Comment: You can do this in Android. If you get yourself an Android tablet then cache a few areas.

You could get street details from OpenStreetMap, but then you need a software to view them, which isn't easy... Here's a possiblity, but I haven't tried it: http://offmaps.com/

Comment: Maybe you can use tile caching also? See http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/65621/4630

Answer (score 2):

GoogleMaps is now offering 'off-line' mode, so you can do this without any GIS or programming at all. The trick is you'll need Android Ice Cream Sandwich or Jelly Bean: [A new Google Maps app for smartphone and tablets](http://google-latlong.blogspot.com/2013/07/a-new-google-maps-app-for-smartphone.html)

> The offline maps feature for Android is also no longer available. Instead we’ve created a new way for you to access maps offline by simply entering “OK Maps” into the search box when viewing the area you want for later. Finally, My Maps functionality is not supported in this release but will return to future versions of the app. People who want to create powerful custom maps can still do so with Maps Engine Lite on desktop.

Comment: Up to 5 Separate Regions can be downloaded to each account/tablet  for true offline maps Nokia (HERE) Maps download full countries and can be used for Navigation in Offline mode.

Comment: @Mapperz thanks for the suggestion but I don't have android. As mentioned I will like to have this on an ipod.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easiest in Google Earth, where you can directly save the extents to a JPEG. If you have a Pro Account, you can set the output resolution and also save to PDF.
[Source](http://support.google.com/earth/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=148146).

You might also be interested in [this](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/earth/6NpHZIbu8Fs) which explains caching various places so that Google Earth can be used in offline mode. You can store up to 2GB of imagery this way, which is quite substantial.

Edit: Per your edit, it seems that GE is not for what you are looking. A manual way to solve your question would be to "print" the current view, which opens a new window. From there you can save the page as `Web Page, complete` (in Firefox), which saves a folder containing the image. Inside said folder is an image aptly named staticmap.png.

You don't need to change the URL if you pan/zoom around, so you can save the page multiple times, thereby giving you your desired maps.

Assuming you save the files to a folder, this Python script will move all the images in the subfolders to the main folder specified at run time.

```python
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askdirectory
import os, shutil

Tk().withdraw()
folder = askdirectory()

for i,dirname in enumerate([x[0] for x in os.walk(folder) if x[0] != folder]):

    old = "{0}\\staticmap.png".format(dirname)
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(old)
    new = "{0}{1}{2}".format(name, i, ext)

    os.rename(old, new)
    shutil.move(new, folder)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't have a pro account. Also I need the dual language labels that are available on google maps.

Comment: You don't need a Pro account to save imagery. Also, it doesn't look like GM offers [dual language labels](http://google-latlong.blogspot.com/2011/10/single-language-labels-in-google-maps.html) anymore....

Comment: I just read that article myself, I swear yesterday I saw displayed both at the same time. There must be a workaround for that. But it's not the main question at this time.

Comment: Edited my post to reflect your edit to OP. I'm still looking around for a more automated method.

Comment: ok I think I solved the mystery about the dual language, it's possible to do in GE. However I will need to import these maps into my ipod so either a pdf or jpg, I will not have GE with me.

Comment: Print Screen and save the maps you need

Comment: @Paul I have tried what you just described.I am not sure if this is what you meant but I have many small images saved and not just one static.png but it will take me a long time to rename all these smaller images or to navigate a map unless I can somehow combine them into one bigger image.

Comment: Assuming you ran the script, you'll have a lot of sequentially named images. [BRU](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) is immensely useful, as you can use a text file to bulk rename files. I really hope you weren't expecting 1 single image out of this that allowed for zooming/panning...That would be immensely difficult to create.

Comment: @Paul I did not run the script because I don't know where or how to run it. I was hoping for a tool where I could type a province/county name and download the map at a certain zoom level.

Comment: Download Python 2.7.2, save the script with .py extension, point it to the folder containing all the subfolders. You really should lower your expectations, however. What you are hoping for is not something than can easily be whipped out.

Answer (score 1):

There is possibility to download the Google Maps by free software like Terra Incognita ([link](https://sourceforge.net/p/terraincognita2/wiki/Home/)). It can be georeferenced and tiled raster format (GeoTIFF or JPG).

[image: Terra Incognita 2.0]

Instruction ([link](https://sourceforge.net/p/terraincognita2/wiki/save_tutorial/)):

> ```
> 1. Select area which is interesting for you
>     ◦ you can use menu 'selection' to switch to selection mode
>     ◦ or you can hold Ctrl key to create selection various ways how to create selection is described later
> 2. Select map source from menu
>     ◦ this can be done also before selecting area
> 3. Zoom up to resolution which you want to have used in saved map
>     ◦ you can select resolution in menu 'zoom levels' list
>     ◦ or you can click to map to zoom up until your detail level is reached
> 4. Go to menu 'file' and select 'save map'
>     ◦ you don't need to wait until map is saved, save operation will continue on background
>     ◦ if you want to save various maps for the same area you must continue on step 2.
> 5. Go to menu 'selection' and select 'clear selection'
>     ◦ this will remove selection and remove dimmed layer
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try GoogleMapsRipper from http://www.blueblackworks.com
“GoogleMapsRipper is mapping software that allows you to download both satellite imagery, topographic and road maps from Google Maps, Bing Maps and OpenStreet Maps. “

Comment: I'd be leery of using that except for personal use, and in small amounts. The site mentions that you can't batch it too quickly without the risk of banning.

Answer (score 0):

Also try Google Maps Downloader from http://www.bigeastsolutions.com/index.html
You can download Google satellite maps